# ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) always returns 0 for X and Y coordinates

Tags: unity

I'm trying to convert the mouse position (Input.mousePosition) into world points, but for whatever reason the X and Y coordinates are always, always 0.

Here, I printed mousePosition and ScreenToWorldPoint()'s output:

[image: Debug Logs]

The -10 in the Z is understandable, but why do I get 0s in X and Y regardless of the actual, varying mouse position?

This is inside a custom display I set inside Game View (1440x3040). I tried Free Aspect, but that didn't change anything.

I tried parenting the script to an empty game object centered on origin just in case, but that didn't do anything either.

The code:

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Debug.Log(mousePos);
Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);
```

Or, more generally:

```
private bool hitProjectile() {
    bool hit = false;
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Debug.Log(mousePos);
    Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);

    if ((mousePos.x >= (pt.position.x - radius) && mousePos.x <= (pt.position.x + radius)) &&
        (mousePos.y >= (pt.position.y - radius) && mousePos.y <= (pt.position.y + radius)))
        hit = true;

    return hit;
}
```

The game is in 2D, the camera is perspective, and I'm using URP. The script is trying to determine if the mouse clicked on a circle (/w a CircleCollider2D).

What the hell is going on? I hope this is not a URP thing. I've had nothing but bad experiences with it.

Comment: Also, don't forget to search for [existing Q&A about your issue](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158815/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory I did, and I did in fact check out the documentation — multiple times. I guess I glossed over the z position, because I don't remember ever having this problem before, despite having done it many, many times. Maybe I accounted for the camera offset beforehand, which I didn't do now because I just wanted to see that the code I'd written so far was working before proceeding; or maybe it was something else. Whatever the case, it works now, and that's what matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have trouble with an API method, your first step should be to [check the documentation on that method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html):

> ## Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint
>
> `public Vector3 ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3 position);`
> `public Vector3 ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3 position, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye eye);`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **position**    A screen space position (often mouse x, y), *plus a z position for depth* (for example, a camera clipping plane).
> - **eye** By default, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Mono. Can be set to Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Left or Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Right for use in stereoscopic rendering (e.g., for VR).
>
> **Returns**
>
> **Vector3** The worldspace point created by converting the screen space point *at the provided distance z from the camera plane.*

Note the emphasis I've added on the z depth. Your code doesn't tell the camera what depth it wants the world point to be at. It just converts the 2D vector `Input.mousePosition` into a 3D vector implicitly. That implicit version puts a zero in the z coordinate. And of course if you take *any* screen position at zero depth from the camera, you get the camera's location itself. The frustum hasn't had any room to fan out.

Try something more like this:

```
Vector3 screenPosDepth = Input.mousePosition;
// Give it a depth. Maybe a raycast depth, maybe a clipping plane...
screenPosDepth.z = 5.0f; 
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosDepth);
```

For example, if you want the projected point to have the same depth from the camera as some other transform `target`, you can write:

```
screenPosDepth.z = Vector3.Dot(
                      camera.transform.forward,
                      target.position - camera.transform.position
                  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions here...

First off, try setting the mouse position's z to a positive value. As I recall it's to do with the near clipping plane (in the Camera settings). Set it to a value greater than that and it should work.

Secondly, take a look at OnMouseEnter(). It's called on a MonoBehaviour when the mouse cursor enters it. If you cache this value in a variable (and clear it on OnMouseExit()) you can just query the variable when the mouse button is down...

Danny